# Should I use `set -u` in my terminal? Why does it break autocomplete for git?

Tags: bash, terminal, git, autocomplete

I added `set -u` (equiv. `set -o nounset`) to `.bashrc`, but now some tab autocompletes fail with errors about unset variables. One example is for `git` autocompletes.

Would this be a `git` autocomplete bug or is it generally a bad idea to use `set -u` in an interactive terminal? Is there an alternative way to protect myself from myself without breaking autocompletes?

*(I have the same problem using "git bash" on Windows/cygwin, and with RHEL.)*

Comment: Protect yourself from what?

Comment: Protect myself from running commands using variables without first setting all of the variables. For instance, sometimes I am hand picking commands from some documentation where the documentation makes use of variables. If I don't 'pick' the command that would set a variable needed in a command that does gets run...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -u` from the Bourne shell or its more explicit `set -o nounset` from the Korn shell (both are POSIX) is more of a programming tool, used to detect typos or use of initialised variables in your code.

That's a programming style choice. Once it's set, you can't have your code dereference unset variables, which means that you have to write your code differently.

For instance, you can't have:

```
if [ -n "$TERM" ]; then
  echo running in a terminal
fi
```

You need to work around `nounset` with `${TERM-}` in place of `$TERM` or use `[[ -v TERM ]]`.

Some goes with most other options such as `errexit` or `failglob` or `pipefail` which change the way the shell works and for which code writers need to adapt their code.

Now, in interactive shells, that wouldn't be a problem if you were not using code written by others.

The problem is that  bash doesn't have the equivalent of zsh's `emulate -L` where third party functions can explicitly request a local sane baseline of options for their own code.

In zsh, completion code usually does:

```
some-completion-function() {
  emulate -L zsh # default set of options in the zsh emulation set locally
  set -o extendedglob -o errreturn # additional local options as needed

  code here not impacted by the users options
}
```

There's no equivalent in bash and while recent versions of `bash` have `local -` (from ash) to set a local scope for the options set by `set`, there's no equivalent for the options set by `shopt`. And as there's no equivalent of `emulate`, you'd need to hardcode all the options to their default value the list of which varies with the bash version.

Worth, the bash_completion (which is a separate project independent from bash itself) changes the options from the default globally (not only for itself) and expects you not to change it. For instance, it sets `extglob` and `progcomp`.

You'll find that it sometimes sets options temporarily such as `verbose`, `noglob` or `nullglob` clunkily by saving the old setting in a variable and restoring afterwards.

In both bash and zsh, there are even options that affect the way code is parsed, so those should be set after the completion code (or any third party code) is loaded. In zsh, most of the completion code is *autoloaded* on first use, and the autoloading can be done independently of the user's options or aliases (`-z` and `-U` options of `autoload`), but again there's no equivalent in bash.

So you'll find that there are a lot of options which once changed from their default value cause the bash completion to fail (`noglob`, `nounset`, `errexit`, `errreturn`, `failglob` and probably more). Changing the `$IFS` value IIRC causes problems as well (or at least used to). While some of those may be considered as bugs of bash_completion, in most cases, you can't really blame them as the problem is that  bash has no facility to cope with requirements for different sets of options.

So if you're changing the options, be ready for some third party code you use in your shell to fail.